# Trying to correct simple array program

Tags: java, arrays, output

I'm trying to get some practice with Java before starting a new programming class. To do this, I decided to remake so old Perl programs I made from an earlier class. The original Perl file entered numbers entered by the user into an array and would output the array in four ways: the numbers as entered, ascending order, descending order, and the just the largest and smallest numbers.

I looked through several examples here and elsewhere online to trouble-shoot and while the program compiles, the output is wrong. As is, the array is outputted a couple dozen times, only outputting the numbers as entered. I think I have the four loops set up wrong, but I'm still learning Java so there's likely something I missed. Here's the Java code as it is now:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayOutPut {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    static String convertToString(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i : numbers) {
            builder.append(numbers);
            builder.append(",");
        }
        builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1);
        return builder.toString();

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int userInput;
        int Largest = 0, Smallest = 0;

        System.out.print(
                "This program takes a set of integers from the user, and then outputs the results to the screen in four ways:\n");
        System.out.print(
                "the order they were entered seperated by a comma and a space, in ascending order, in descending order, and as Largest:Smallest.\n\n");
        // explain to the user what the program does, needs, etc.
        System.out.print("Please enter a number or -1 to end: ");
        userInput = input.nextInt();
        while (userInput != -1) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number or -1 to end: ");
            numbers.add(userInput);
            userInput = input.nextInt();
        }

        // Prints the array contents as entered
        String sort = convertToString(numbers);
        System.out.println(sort);
        // prints numbers ascending
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(sort);
        }
        // prints numbers descending, largest first
        for (int i = numbers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(sort);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            int number = numbers.get(i);
            if (i < Smallest) {
                Smallest = i;
            }
            if (i > Largest) {
                Largest = i;
            }
            System.out.println(Largest + Smallest);
        }
    }
}
```

For additional reference, here's the original Perl program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
use Modern::Perl;
my (@numbers, $userInput);# declare the array and more than one variable at a time
print("\nThis program takes a set of integers from the user, and 
\nthen outputs the results to the screen in four ways:
\nthe ordered they were entered seperated by a comma and a space, 
\nin ascending order, in descending order, and as Largest:Smallest.\n\n"); # explain to the user what is does, needs, etc
    print "Please enter a number or -1 to end: ";
    chomp ($userInput = <>); #loop is primed
    if ($userInput == -1) {
    say "\nThere's no numbers to process.\n";
}
else{       
while($userInput != -1) {
push (@numbers, $userInput); 
#Push the variable $userInput into  @numbers. 
        print "Please enter a number or -1 to end: ";
        chomp ($userInput = <>);
  }
}
#Don't declare the @numbers array again, otherwise that'll clear out the entered numbers.
$" = ", ";
print "@numbers\n";
my @upsorted = sort {$a <=> $b} @numbers;
#prints numbers ascending, smallest first. 
#Don't use $a, $b, or any number as a variable because they're reserved.
$" = ", ";
print "@upsorted\n";
my @downsorted = sort {$b <=> $a} @numbers;
#prints numbers descending, largest first
$" = ", ";
print "@downsorted\n";
print "$downsorted[0]:$upsorted[0]\n"; 
#must be set off with a blank line above and below
##End of program
```

Okay, as a quick update, I've finally gotten the program to run after looking up comparators on tutorialspoint.com. Here's where the code is at now:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayOutPut {

    static String convertToString(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i : numbers){
        builder.append(i);
        builder.append(",");
            }
        builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1);
    return builder.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int userInput, largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE, smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    System.out.println("This program takes a set of integers from the user, and then "
        + "outputs the results to the screen in four ways:");
    System.out.println("the order they were entered seperated by a comma and a space, "
        + "in ascending order, in descending order, and as Largest:Smallest.");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("This program takes a set of integers from the user, and then outputs the results to the screen in four ways:\n");
    System.out.print("the order they were entered seperated by a comma and a space, in ascending order, in descending order, and as Largest:Smallest.\n\n");
    //explain to the user what the program does, needs, etc.
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number or -1 to end: ");
        userInput = input.nextInt();
        if (userInput != -1) {
            numbers.add(userInput);
            largest = Math.max(largest, userInput);
            smallest = Math.min(smallest, userInput);
        }
    } while (userInput != -1);

    //Prints the array contents as entered
    String sort = convertToString(numbers);
    Comparator cmp = Collections.reverseOrder();
    System.out.println(sort);
    Collections.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println(convertToString(numbers));
    Collections.sort(numbers, Comparator.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println(convertToString(numbers));
    System.out.printf("Smallest = %d, Largest = %d%n", smallest, largest);
        }
    }
```

My only concern is that when I compiled, I got a note that says the program uses unchecked or unsafe operations, and that I should recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of your code? And share the input, the output you got, and the output you expected?

Comment: submitted an edit which fixes the indentation of the code. OP, if you're in Eclipse, you can right-click the file in the package explorer and go `Source > Format`.

Comment: OP, `convertToString(ArrayList)` can be substituted with `List.toString()`, which does that automatically.

Comment: `builder.append(numbers);` you're appending the whole array at each iteration no ? `builder.append(i);` would be better.

Comment: In your last loop, `number` isn't used, is that intended ? looks like you wanted to compare it with Smallest and Largest, but you compared `i` instead. Also, with Smallest = 0 at the start, chances are that it will never get replaced ; try to initialize Smallest with the highest value of your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if using Java 8+, I would use a `StringJoiner` in `convertToString`<sup>**1**</sup>

```
static String convertToString(List<Integer> numbers) {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
    numbers.stream().map(String::valueOf).forEach(sj::add);
    return sj.toString();
}
```

Second, you need to `sort` and call `convertToString` again to print the results. Prefer variables with lower case names. And you can eliminate the loops with built-in functions. Check that `userInput` isn't `-1` before adding it to your `List`. And I would prefer a `do-while`. Something like,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    int userInput, largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE, smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    System.out.println("This program takes a set of integers from the user, and then "
            + "outputs the results to the screen in four ways:");
    System.out.println("the order they were entered seperated by a comma and a space, "
            + "in ascending order, in descending order, and as Largest:Smallest.");
    System.out.println();
    // explain to the user what the program does, needs, etc.
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number or -1 to end: ");
        userInput = input.nextInt();
        if (userInput != -1) {
            numbers.add(userInput);
            largest = Math.max(largest, userInput);
            smallest = Math.min(smallest, userInput);
        }
    } while (userInput != -1);

    // Prints the array contents as entered
    String sort = convertToString(numbers);
    System.out.println(sort);
    Collections.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println(convertToString(numbers));
    Collections.sort(numbers, Comparator.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println(convertToString(numbers));
    System.out.printf("Smallest = %d, Largest = %d%n", smallest, largest);
}
```

#### **Update**

Based on your edit(s), you're using Java 7 (not Java 8+). In which case, your code (glad to hear it is working), can be "corrected" with a *typed* `Comparator`. Something like,

```
Comparator<Integer> cmp = Collections.<Integer> reverseOrder();
```

Which will give you an `Integer` based `Comparator` in *reverse* order.  However, it's also possible to create a *custom* `Comparator`. Such as,

```
Comparator<Integer> cmp = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        if (o1 == null) {
            return (o2 == null) ? 0 : -1;
        }
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
};
```

And then you can use it (and reverse it) like

```
System.out.println(sort);
Collections.sort(numbers, cmp);
System.out.println(convertToString(numbers));
Collections.sort(numbers, cmp.reversed());
System.out.println(convertToString(numbers));
```

<sup>**1**<sub>And, please prefer the `List` interface over the `ArrayList` concrete type.</sub></sup>

Comment: Okay I tried Elliot Frisch's suggestion, and I got 6 compile errors, all regarding line 8,

Comment: What exactly is line 8.

Comment: (numbers.stream().map(String::valueOf).forEach(sj::add);                The first error expected a ')' at the first colon in (String::valueOf), the second is illegal start of expression at the second colon of (String::valueOf), and the third error expected a semi-colon at the end parenthesis of (String::valueOf). The other errors are the same, except at (sj::add).

Comment: I've switched back to StringBuilder and I'm using import java.util.*; but I'm still getting a compiler error. The error message reads as `cannot find symbol`  for `Collections.sort(numbers, Comparator.reverseOrder());`.  The putty system I'm using is focused on the dot between comparator and reverseOrder.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using data structures of the `java.util` package, I can suggest an easy way of sorting the elements in the `ArrayList`. Provided that `numbers` is the `ArrayList` holding all the numbers to work upon, do the following:

- Display the numbers in the ArrayList `numbers` as they are
- Make a `TreeSet` of `numbers`. A `TreeSet` automatically sorts its elements in ascending order **NOTE: A TreeSet will only hold unique elements. So, if elements inside the list are repeated, they will get deleted. Only a single copy of each element will be stored in the Set.**
- Re-initialize `numbers` as the TreeSet made out of `numbers`. This is because a TreeSet can be displayed only in one order. Now, display the elements of `numbers` from first to last for ascending order and from last to first for descending order.
- Finally, display the first and last elements of `numbers` as the smallest and largest numbers respectively.

Here's a code.

```
import java.util.*;
class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers <--- holds all the numbers 
        System.out.println("The numbers are:");
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.size();i++)
        System.out.print(numbers.get(i).intValue()+" ");

        TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<Integer>(numbers);
        numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(ts);
        System.out.println("\nThe numbers in ascending order are:");
        for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++)
        System.out.print(numbers.get(i).intValue()+" ");

        System.out.println("\nThe numbers in descending order are:");
        for(int i=numbers.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
        System.out.print(numbers.get(i).intValue()+" ");

        System.out.println("\nThe smallest number is "+numbers.get(0).intValue());

        System.out.println("The largest number is "+numbers.get(numbers.size()-1).intValue());
    }
}
```

I tested it with an ArrayList having elements `1 2 5 6 7` and here's the **output**:

```
The numbers are:
7 5 6 1 2 
The numbers in ascending order are:
1 2 5 6 7 
The numbers in descending order are:
7 6 5 2 1 
The smallest number is 1
The largest number is 7
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: After trying this version, I found that I could shave off five lines of code compared to the StringBuilder I was using before.